# 403 error when accessing custom webparts/ workflow tasks unless administrators accesses them first

Tags: 403

We have a Site with custom web-parts and workflow tasks (Designed by `InfoPath`).

Recently we realize we have this issue whereby non-admin users (i.e. users who are not in `Administrators` group in AD) cannot access any of this custom parts. On access they will get a generic

> 403 error.

However, if any user belonging to the `Administrators` group accesses any of the custom parts, they will have no problem accessing.

Not only that, once any of the Admin users accesses the custom parts, any other users who are non-admin will then be suddenly able to access!

We tried adding `Authenticated Users` group and `Users` group with the required rights(not full control) to the File Security of the `bin` and `app_bin` folders but to no avail.

Would appreciate if anyone can share their thoughts and advice on this. Thanks

Comment: about the file security: did you do the same steps like in https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2013/04/30/intermittent-http-403-forbidden-error-while-trying-to-browse-to-a-sharepoint-web-app/

Comment: @Celophysis hey yes. I gave Authenticated Users n even Users those rights for the bin folders. Still doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Did you looked into the SharePoint log files for more details? It will show you what resource access failed in 403.

Comment: @Amal Hashim Yes. But it just says 403 error. No specific mention of resource location which failed. I tried checking the logs as well as monitoring through Process Monitor too

Comment: As an interim solution you can try https://github.com/spjeff/spbestwarmup and see if that resolves the issue.. I am recommending this based on what you said like if admin opens the page then it works for all users.. Just schedule this to run every day morning.